# ASP.NET 5 Identity - custom SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have a MVC 6 project (vNext) and I am playing around with the ASP.NET Identity. In my case I don't want to use the build-in stuff which uses the EF (SignInManager, UserManager, UserStore). I have an external database and I just want to make a username/password lookup and return a valid cookie. 
So I started writing my own classes.

```
public class MyUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}

public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MyUser>
{
    ...
}
```

In the `MyUserStore` class I am using hard-coded list of users as my store (only for test purposes). And I overrode some methods just to return the data from the hard-coded store.

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<MyUser>
{
    public MyUserManager(
        IUserStore<MyUser> store,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<MyUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<MyUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<MyUser>> passwordValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        IEnumerable<IUserTokenProvider<MyUser>> tokenProviders,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) :
        base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, tokenProviders, logger, contextAccessor)
    {
    }
}
```

Here I made the methods `CheckPasswordAsync` and `VerifyPasswordAsync` to return `true` and `PasswordVerificationResult.Success` respectively just for the test.

```
public class MyClaimsPrincipleFactory : IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUser>
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
            var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return principle;
        });
    }
}

public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<MyUser>
{
    public MySignInManager(MyUserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor = null, ILoggerFactory logger = null)
            : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        // here goes the external username and password look up

        if (userName.ToLower() == "username" && password.ToLower() == "password")
        {
            return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Failed);
        }
    }
}
```

And everything is hooked up in the `Startup` class as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
            .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
            .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And because I didn't manage to create the `MySignInManager` object in the `Startup` code in order to add it into the DI (for later injection in the controllers and views), I am creating it in the `MyAccountController`.

```
public MyAccountController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<MyUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILoggerFactory logger)
{
    SignInManager = new MySignInManager(userManager as MyUserManager, httpContextAccessor, new MyClaimsPrincipleFactory(), optionsAccessor, logger);
}
```

In my `MyLogin` action in the `MyAccount` controller I am calling `PasswordSignInAsync` and I can see that I am getting the cookie with the encoded claims in it (from the `MyClaimsPrincipleFactory`).
When I try to call some other action with the `AuthorizeAttribute` on it I can see that the cookie is in the request header but I am unauthorized (more precisely, because I didn't remove the built-in default ASP.NET Identity Authentication from the visual studio sample template, I am redirected to the Account/Login instead).

Is this the right way of customizing ASP.NET Identity and what am I missing here?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line

return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
        

and see what it returns. My guess is that it too is returning SignInResult.Failed.

I would return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success) instead of calling the base class...
hth

Comment: Yeah I tried that one. When I am returning Success without calling the base method, I am not getting the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here was that I didn't provide the `AuthenticationType` of my `ClaimsIdentity` object. [This blog post](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/) helped me.

> To have IsAuthenticated set to true, you need to specify an authentication type in the ctor:
>
> var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, “Custom”);

Answer (score 12):

I had problems too trying to use a custom `SignInManager` and turns out to be really easy after all to implement.

In `Startup.cs`, after the default implementation of `services.Identity`

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

You only need to inject into the built-in DI the following:

```
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<MyApplicationUser>, MySignInManager>();
```

The default `SignInManager` is overwrited by the custom one.

Answer (score 7):

In my project I have a working implementation of identity without using EF. I think maybe you are implementing more than you need to. UserManager and SignInManager are not tied to EF. You can implement those if you want but you don't have to just to get away from EF. you only really need to implement the UserStore and RoleStore and maybe PasswordHasher if you are needing to validate hard coded password for testing.

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserPasswordStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserEmailStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserLoginStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserRoleStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserClaimStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserPhoneNumberStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserLockoutStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserTwoFactorStore<SiteUser>, UserStore<SiteUser>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IRoleStore<SiteRole>, RoleStore<SiteRole>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<SiteUser>, SiteUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<SiteUser, SiteRole>>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IPasswordHasher<SiteUser>, SitePasswordHasher<SiteUser>>());
services.AddIdentity<SiteUser, SiteRole>();
```

the above shows the items I am implementing to bypass Entity Framework,
my AccountController for example takes constructor parameters for

```
    UserManager<SiteUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<SiteUser> signInManager
```

which are the standard identity UserManager and SignInManager that I did not have to setup with DI services they are registered for me by this line:

```
services.AddIdentity<SiteUser, SiteRole>();
```

you can [see the code for that extension method here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs). It is part of Identity not part of EFIdentity. 
You can see that I also implemented IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory. The only reason I implemented that was to add some custom claims, I did not need to do that to get away from EF.

Comment: I may not really have needed to implement IRoleStore since it isn't actually used anywhere in the starter web app code. My "implementation" just throws NotImplementedException in every method but I never encounter the exception because it is not used anywhere. Presumably in future versions of the VS web app template there will be controllers/views to manage roles and it will be needed then but not now.

Comment: Okey, I removed my custom `SignInManager` and `UserManager`. Still when I try to go to the action with `Authorize` attribute I am getting 302 and it redirects me to the /Account/Login - the default one. But I have MyAccountController working with my custom IUserStore, MyUser, etc....

Comment: I realized that after I login I have my `ClaimsIdentity` in the `User.Identity` object. But the `IsAuthenticated` property is `false`. In the fiddler I can see that the cookie is there and it is passed with each request.

Comment: you do still have this line in Startup.cs right? app.UseIdentity(); that is the one that sets up cookie auth

Answer (score 5):

You can register a custom `SignInManager` for Dependency Injection by using the [`IdentityBuilder.AddSignInManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilder.addsigninmanager) method within your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<MyUser, IdentityRole<int>, SqlContext, int>>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<IdentityRole<int>, SqlContext, int>>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

There is no reason that the `SignInManager` you have implemented cannot be registered for DI in the same way.